# Android: Sending Network Information via SMS

Tags: android, eclipse, sms, smsmanager

I'm making an app that at some point will send the network information about the current device to a new number.
I am able to send the message fine but when the message is received the formatting/content of the text is strange.

I'm running my app on a 2.2 emulator.

My code for sending the message is:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); //SMS Manager
ConnectivityManager connManager; //Connectivity Manager

NetworkInfo network = connManager.getNetworkInfo(networkType); //Getting the network type

String sendTo = "5556"; //Number to send to
String myMsg = ("Network: " + network.toString()); //Message will contain

smsManager.sendTextMessage(sendTo, null, myMsg, null, null); //Sending the message
```

The received message is shown below:

[image: Received SMS message]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NetworkInfo.toString()` reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of
>   this object. Subclasses are encouraged to override this method and
>   provide an implementation that takes into account the object's type
>   and data. The default implementation is equivalent to the following
>   expression:
>
> `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`
>
> See [Writing a useful `toString` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#writing_toString) if you intend implementing your
>   own `toString` method.

Means that the default implementation of `toString()` does not give any real information that you can use.

Comment: So does this mean that I would need to create my own toString method in order to make the rest of the message readable?

Comment: Or just use some other methods of the NetworkInfo class, like `getTypeName()` - depending on what you want.

Comment: That'll do nicely! Thank you.